# vbscript X and Cancel not doing what they should

Tags: vbscript

im writing a code in **vbscript** where it will ask the user for input and then run certain files according to the input and i have the else so that it will redo the if else sequence when you type something that isnt an option but when **i try to press cancel or the red 'X' it acts as if i have put in an invalid input** and goes over the else sequence.

```
Dim sInput
sInput = InputBox("input")
If sInput = "input1" or sInput = "input2" Then
   set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
   shell.run "file.bat"
elseif sInput = "exit" or sInput = "Exit" Then
   WScript.Quit
else
   name=msgbox ("   That is not a valid response",0+16,"ERROR")
   set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
   shell.run "input.vbs"
end if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to restart the script.

Use a loop instead. End the loop when the user entered a valid option, or quit the entire program if requested.

```
Option Explicit

Dim Shell, input, button

Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Do
  input = InputBox("input")
  If IsEmpty(input) Or LCase(input) = "exit" Then WScript.Quit

  input = LCase(Trim(input))

  If input = "input1" Or input = "input2" Then
    Shell.Run "file.bat"
    Exit Do
  Else
    button = MsgBox("That is not a valid response.", vbExclamation + vbRetryCancel, "ERROR")
    If button = vbCancel Then Exit Do
  End If
Loop
```

Notes:

- `Option Explicit` makes variable declaration mandatory. It's a good idea to always have this enabled.
- `IsEmpty()` is true when the user pressed the Cancel button (or the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key) in the `InputBox` - but this will work **only before** the response is manipulated in any way, such as `LCase` or `Trim`. Supporting the Cancel button is more intuitive than having a special "exit" keyword, so maybe you should get rid of that.
- The various constants you can use with `MsgBox` are [described on ss64.com](https://ss64.com/vb/msgbox.html) and in more detal in the [official VBScript language reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//sfw6660x%28v%3Dvs.85%29).
  You can change what <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> do in each `MsgBox` by using the `vbDefaultButton1` or `vbDefaultButton2` constants.
- The `Do` loop without any conditions (`Do`/`Loop While ...` or `Do`/`Loop Until ...`) will run forever - be sure not to forget using `Exit Do` or `WScript.Quit()`. (If you do, killing the Script with the Task Manager will get you out of it.)